# Ссылка на Яндекс Такси с определенной точкой отправления

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть ли в Яндекс Такси такая возможность, чтобы при переходе по ссылке пользователь попадал на сайт Яндекс Такси, и у него была сразу вписана конечная точка отправления?

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашла такую статейку  - https://yandex.ru/dev/taxi/doc/dg/concepts/deeplinks.html , которая ссылается на геокодер https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geocoder/

Comment: "конечная точка отправления" - это какой-то загадочный термин, который чисто логически означает, что пассажир никуда не переместится =)